# How do you italicize something with underscores on Stackoverflow?

Tags: support, markdown

How do you italicize something with an underscore in it on Stackoverflow et al? If I try underscores around a word with an underscore, it comes out literally, for example

_blah_blah_ (not italicized)

*blah* (italicized)

*blah_blah* (not italicized)

*blah* (italicized)

Trying with the text tool doesn't work either. It puts a single star on either side of the highlighted word (my third example), which doesn't highlight the word.

So if you can italicize words with underscores, how do you do it?

Comment: Try this: `*unique\_names*`

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find it through search. Maybe close it as a dupe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Executive Summary

*There_is_no_one_way_to_do_it*

> `<i>There_is_no_one_way_to_do_it</i>`

### Really though

*There_are_several*

> `_There\_are\_several_`

### But...

*It's*_*a*_*Secret*

> `*It's*_<i>a</i>_*Secret*`